# Custom DateTime model binder for ApiController

Tags: asp.net-core, model-binding

I am creating API using ASP.NET Web Api and ApiController. There is a need to adjust all datetime values to utc. Let's say there is a model

```
    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

And Controller:

```
    [ApiController]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/profucts")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Product product)
        {
            //.... do smth
            return Ok();
        }
```

Is there a way to plug into binding of DateTime properties of model classes and do some adjustments there?

Creating custom datetime model binder and and registering it globally via `...config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new MyDateTimeBinderProvider());` doesn't work as model binder never gets hit.

Binder code:

```
public class DateTimeBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueProviderResult.FirstValue))
        {
            return null;
        }
        DateTime value;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(valueProviderResult.FirstValue, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out value))
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(value.ToUniversalTime());
        }
        else
        {
          //add error
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Created` property is unique within your project? Could you please share what format of your `Created` you are submitting?

Comment: Let's just say I would like to make sure all DateTime and especially DateTimeOffset properties are in UTC without timezone info so I don't have to adjust them manually

Comment: In that case, you would require a model binder and you have to call that binder inside your provider. Finally call your provider in your service. Can you share your `MyDateTimeBinderProvider` and inside your Provider how are you calling your ModelBinder this is the key here.

Comment: Added binder code - it is pretty simple. But the point is that it is acyually never gets called. Controller consumes appliation/json, so apparently complex model binder just deserializes body and doesn't call any binders for properties.
So probably question should be - what is (if any) an extensibility point to adjust datetime values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Creating custom datetime model binder and and registering it globally
> via ...config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new
> MyDateTimeBinderProvider()); doesn't work as model binder never gets
> hit.

Based on your scenario and description, it seems you were not able to hit your model binder. To call model binder within your MyDateTimeBinderProvider we ought to define your modelbinder name in [BinderTypeModelBinder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider).

In my test I have successfully able to call, I am mostly concentrating why not your binder get hitted rather the conversion stuff. You could have a look below:

Model:

Let's assume we have following model:

```cs
public class MyProductClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

Model Binder:

```cs
public class DateConversionModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {

        public DateConversionModelBinder()
        {

        }

        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            var model = new MyProductClass();

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I have simply created a demo DateConversionModelBinder. No additional logic has written.

In case you need conversion code:

```cs
public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }
            var request = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var stream = request.Body;// At the begining it holding original request stream                    
            var originalReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var originalContent = originalReader.ReadToEndAsync();

           
            var retrieveObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(originalContent.Result);

            var model = new MyProductClass();


            DateTime dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(retrieveObject.created);


            TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("China Standard Time");

            DateTime cstTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime, TimeZoneInfo.Local, cstZone);

            DateTime fromLocalTimeToUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(cstTime, cstZone);



            model.Created = fromLocalTimeToUTC;
            model.Name = retrieveObject.name;



            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

Model Binding Provider:

```cs
public class ProductEntityBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
    {
        public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            }

            if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(MyProductClass))
            {

                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateConversionModelBinder));
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Note:** As you can see, I have defined Model and ModelBinder Name within th provider.

Program.cs File:

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options => { options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ProductEntityBinderProvider()); });
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:**  As you can see, I can hit DateConversionModelBinder via ProductEntityBinderProvider. Please [have a look on the official document here for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider)

Comment: That is a very comprehensive answer, thanks
But the problem is a bit different - I would like to do datetime adjustments for all datetime properties of my models. Custom datetime binder works if action input is other from application/json.
In case of application/json it just deserializes request body and skips property binding.
So this is where I am looking for an extensibility point

Comment: ValueProvider cannot retrieve value from FromBody; thus it will be skipped,. Therefore, you have to extract request body itself. Try my way. By the way, your initial convern was why binder doesn't get hit.