# Customizing Identity in ASP.NET Core 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to add some additional fields to my identity user.
I found that this is fairly straightforward by creating a new class inheriting from IdentityUser and passing the inherited class to the appropriate builders.

That's fine and the user table has the additional fields. However, I am struggling to find out how to customize the request body for the route "/register" because there, only email and password are being requested. Usually, I would adjust these things in my controller class but the IdentityController is a black box I don't have access to.

PS: I am not using Blazor. I am using ASP.Net purely as a backend.
PS2: I am upgrading a non-Identity ASP.Net Core 7 project with Identity Core 8

All the information I got so far comes from the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0
But they always mention their custom UIs, which is not what I am looking for.

Here is my custom user class

```cs
public class AuthUser: IdentityUser
{
    public static readonly string KEY_PREFIX = "user";

    // Would like to have a custom id generator but haven't 
    // figured out how to do that either
    // [Key]
    // public string Id { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [PersonalData]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [PersonalData]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

The database class:

```cs
public class ApiDbContext: IdentityDbContext<AuthUser>
{
    public ApiDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApiDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

And here are bits of my Program.cs

```cs
/* ... */

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

// Setup Database
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(conn));

// Setup Auth
builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<AuthUser>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApiDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

/* ... */

app.MapIdentityApi<AuthUser>();

// Not sure if this part is needed
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();

/* ... */
```

Comment: Did you try to add `[Required]` on top of added property/ies?

Comment: Yes, I tried with `[Required]` and `[PersonalData]`. Still no luck.

Comment: Okay, can you share more code or replicable solution?

Comment: I've updated the original post with code examples but don't know how useful it is.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I was not working yet with the latest ASP.NET Identity, but you can use `IdentityUser<TKey>` to define what type you wanna use as key.

Comment: Then you want to alter how things are configured in your `ApiDbContext` overriding `OnModelCreating` method. Call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` first. It should actually take into a count attributes. So, maybe you don't need to do anything.

Comment: I am not sure you actually can alter how endpoints by default behave. I might be wrong. There are two possible options. Find out which middleware is taking care of request related to ASP.NET Identity and if possible replace them with your own to change the behaviour. Second option is to use default register endpoint and as a next step to force user to fill in info you need thought your own endpoint.

Comment: May I know `"I am struggling to find out how to customize the required form fields in the route "/register" for example because there, only email and password are being requested. Basically, I am trying to find out if the existing IdentityController can be adjusted or if I have to re-implement all of it from scratch."` What you are trying achieve? In request from what you are expecting?

Comment: I have a similar escenario, needed that every user has an OrganizationID, DbContext creates de column on the table and defaults de value to 0, so, I developed another endpoint that creates the "normal" user, then creates de Organization, and then updates the field in the User table. But don't know if this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling to find out how to customize the request body for the
> route "/register" because there, only email and password are being
> requested. Usually, I would adjust these things in my controller class
> but the IdentityController is a black box I don't have access to.

If I got you correctly, you are trying to achieve a scenario where you can have the option to validate the `AuthUser` class properties based on either the request path or the particular page.

Well, this can be implemented in many ways. For instance, you could use [HttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to override the [IActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.iactionfilter?view=aspnetcore-7.0)  and get the reuqest route or action name or even the request path in order to check your request origin.

Then all you need to check your request model properties status whether they are empty.

Finally, based on your model validation status you can build your newly created  `ValidationResult` and update the user.

Another ways, to do that by using [ModelBinderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider)

However, based on your scenario, I think using httpcontext accessor action filter mechanism is more suitable. So I am providing that example.

Let's have a look how we can implement that in practice:

**Check http request context:**

```
public class HttpContextAccessorActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HttpContextAccessorActionFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items["ActionName"] = context.ActionDescriptor.RouteValues["action"];
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

**Note:** Here we are checking our request origin from each http request context by using IHttpContextAccessor.

**Validate request model using IHttpContextAccessor:**

Let's look at the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see I have the request route or action whatever you can say, those are Login and Register. So in the following model validator acion filter we would check two route in order to validate in codming reuqest which is he type of `AuthUser request model`. So no matter, you are in controller or asp.net core Identity page, all you need is to use the `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]` annotation attribute above your class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class ConditionalValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] Actions { get; }

    public ConditionalValidationAttribute(params string[] actions)
    {
        Actions = actions;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = value as AuthUser;

        if (model != null)
        {
            var httpContextAccessor = validationContext.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var actionName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["action"]?.ToString();
            var reqeustPath = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Path;
            if (Actions.Contains(actionName))
            {
                // Validate based on the action
                if (actionName == "Login" && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password)))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Email and Password are required for login.", new[] { nameof(AuthUser.Email), nameof(AuthUser.Password) });
                }
                else if (actionName == "Register" && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.LastName)))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("All fields are required for registration.", new[] { nameof(AuthUser.Email), nameof(AuthUser.Password), nameof(AuthUser.FirstName), nameof(AuthUser.LastName) });
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

**Note:** As you can see, I am checking the model based on each request route and its only going to work with `AuthUser` class properties.

AuthUser Model:

Your model should be as following:

```
[ConditionalValidation("Login", "Register")]
public class AuthUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    
}
```

**Program.cs:**

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<HttpContextAccessorActionFilter>();
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(AuthUser model)
{
    return View("Register");
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you also need a way to implement using [ModelBinderProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941559/custom-datetime-model-binder-for-apicontroller/75947483#75947483), you could [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941559/custom-datetime-model-binder-for-apicontroller/75947483#75947483) or check the [official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#implementing-a-modelbinderprovider).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I'm still having trouble understanding this from a conceptual standpoint. I am using ASP.NET purely as a backend and I have my own React frontend. So I don't think that the backend has an understanding of a Page or a View. Also, I don't only want to validate the request but also be able to implement my own logic on top of the existing register functionality. The way that I am imagining it is that I define my own "/register" endpoint and specify my own request body, implement my own logic, and then call a base function register. Or am I completely missing the point here?

Comment: You can still write your own logic there's no issue with it. If you want to validate `AuthUser`  model based on any reqeust endpoint its absolutely find and it won't conflic your individual logic.  The main concept is you can pass your parameter here in `[ConditionalValidation("Login", "Register")]` and it will validate your model based on your either endpoint, page name or the way  you want.